# I am trying to make a simple server with Go language, Why is it not loading the page but keeps showing the ERR message?

Tags: go, server

I am following a tutorial and I have literally crosschecked everything, It seems not to be working still  ....................................................................

> 

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net/http"
)

func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
       fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
       return
   }
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "POST request succesfull")
   name := r.FormValue("name")
   address := r.FormValue("address")
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "Name = %s\n", name)
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "Address = %s\n", address)

}
func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   if r.URL.Path != "/hello" {
       http.Error(w, "404 not found", http.StatusNotFound)
       return
   }
   if r.Method != "Get" {
       http.Error(w, "method is not supported", http.StatusNotFound)
       return
   }
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello!")
}
func main() {
   fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
   http.Handle("/", fileServer)
   http.HandleFunc("/form", formHandler)
   http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

   fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")

   if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
}
```

[Here is the Error message for all pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpeoU.png)

Comment: Seems to me like you're trying to access the `/form` path. Have you tried removing the `.html` suffix?

Comment: Yeah it's still showing the same thing

"go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'"
This is the message from my terminal

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started#code see step 3

Comment: Try to create a go mod file (`go mod init`) or try to set the module-aware mode to auto (`go env -w GO111MODULE=auto`)

Comment: Hello, for such question it would be practical to provide a curl command which can help to see what you are actually doing which is raising the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one issue in your code, but it is in the `/hello` handler. You are checking if it is a GET using `r.Method != "Get"`, but HTTP methods are in uppercase, so you should use `r.Method != "GET"`, or even better, use the given constant `r.Method != http.MethodGet`. That solves the `/hello` issue for me:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/hello
hello!
```

Now, the `/form` handle issue is not in your code, but happens that you are trying to load `form.html` instead of calling `form`, which can work if you have a file called `form.html` in the `static` subfolder in your project, like this (which is a very minimalist example):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Form</title>
  <body>

    <form method="post" action="/form">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      <label for="address">Address: </label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

That works because you are already handling static files in `http.Handle("/", fileServer)`. I don't know the tutorial you are following, but looks like that was the intention.

Another option to try `form` directly, without HTML could be using something like `curl`:

```
$ curl -d 'name=My+Name&address=My+Address' localhost:8080/form
POST request succesfullName = My Name
Address = My Address
```

There are other tools. The HTML one should be fine for training.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there is one more error in your `helloHandler` function when you compare the request Method, you should compare it with "GET" and not "Get".

For more info look at: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-constants

I ran this code locally it is working fine locally for me. With this Method change I mentioned above. Can you post the exact error you are getting?